# How to display row number in Grid.Mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid.mvc

I want to have a column as row number in [Grid.Mvc](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/). How can I do it?

Comment: Use a view model with a `RowNumber` property and bind a column to it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034460/how-to-display-row-number-in-mvc-webgrid

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ROW_NUMBER() SQL inbuilt method while fetching the data from SQL as shown below:

```
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (ORDER BY EmployeeName) AS Row, 
     EmployeeId, EmployeeName, Salary 
     FROM Employees
```

Then you can bind the Row column from your database to the Grid control as a separate column.